# Socket IO NestJS + Dart + linux system connection failure

Tags: docker, dart, socket.io, operating-system, nestjs

I currently using NestJS for SocketIO server and Flutter for client.

Developing NestJS Server on local mac machine, it works well with dart socket-io client but whenever I tried to deploy my NestJS server code(docker or native ubuntu), connection always fails. (also I tired many times removing node_modules and reinstall...)

I wonder why this happens and how to solve this problem. first I thought it was a problem whit socket's version problem but it might not in this case.

---

Server NestJs version `8.2.5`, Local Machine NestJS version `8.2.5`

Deployment Server: `18.04.6 LTS`, Deployment Docker Image: `node:16-alpine` or `node:14-alpine`

Server side package.json

```
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.4",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^8.4.4",
    "@nestjs/platform-ws": "^8.4.4",
    "socket.io-redis": "^5.4.0",
```

Client Dart pubspec

```
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0
```

---

Client Socket Part

```dart
    socket = io('http://192.168.0.26:9000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': true,
    });
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('connect', (_) => print('connect: ${socket.id}'));
```

---

Server Side Redis Adapter

```js
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import * as redisIoAdapter from 'socket.io-redis';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    const redisAdapter = redisIoAdapter({
      host: '127.0.0.1',  // host.docker.internal
      port: 6379,
    });
    server.adapter(redisAdapter);
    return server;
  }
}


async function bootstrap(port: number) {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app));
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
  await app.listen(port);
}

for (const single of [9000, 9001]) {
  bootstrap(single).then();
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not at docker or socket itself. It was from nginx configure.

I added this code to my nginx conf

```
location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        add_header  Front-End-Https   on;
}
```

then error gone.